# EXCEL - Color cell based on value of adjacent (left) cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to implement a function in my sheet where I can automatically give a certain cell a different color background based on the value of the cell right next to it on the left side.

Example:

[image]

Right now, giving the cell a value of D1, it will color the cell dark red.
I want the cell to the right of D1 to color a light shade of red.

So basically I am trying to reference the cell to the left but I cannot get it to work.
Btw, I am on a Dutch version of Excel so I have to translate formulas to Dutch.

I have tried numerous formulas. I have tried creating a new formula using name generator.

Comment: Then you have to use two conditional formatting rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you have to use two different conditional formatting rule. Please see the following screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks for replying. Is there a way to make this a general rule for the whole worksheet. As in.. If the value of a cell is d1, then always color the cell to the right of it a certain shade of red.

Comment: Just change applies to range. Excel will automatically apply to all cells based on applies date. Here `B3` means all cells between B3 to D9.

Comment: I couldn't add an image to this comment, so I have posted an answer to my original question. I can't figure out why it's not working. It seems to easy, yet so complex.

Comment: Use formula `=U60="d1"` and applyes to range `=V60:Y64`

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. However (sorry),

If I fill in D1, the cell containing D1 turns deep red. This is good
The cell right next to it turns a softer red. This is also good.

But, I want to be able to overwrite the now soft red cell with D1 (of needed), turning it deep red again. Is there a way to apply order, or ranking to formulas, where a certain formula overrules another?

EDIT: Just change the order of the formulas. 

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @listl89 Glad to know! If it helps then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) so that other visitor can know the thread is solved.